# View doesnt work properly when logged out

Tags: views

I have a question about a problem I met. I'm working on Drupal 7 site that has a menu made with a view but for some reason the structure of menu is totaly different when user is logged in than when the user is logged out.
Everything works fine when I'm logged as admin but when I logged out it seems like some of configurations doesnt load. I don't have any errors in console.

I`m not sure what kind of informations from view I can share or will be usefull so I will add every need informations which you asked for.

Adding a code from inspect:
[Image with both inspects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVNpQ.jpg)

Comment: In the view check the 'Access' settings. Maybe there are restrictions based on the role.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is that anonymous users don't have access to the content or fields. The inspect images aren't helpful to determine what permissions could be missing. In the UI, go to *People > permissions* and check that:

- Anonymous users can see published content
- If there are field-level permissions, anonymous can see all the fields involved in the view
- There aren't restrictions to access the view (this is unlikely, the view wouldn't render at all)